# Java - Unable to write on URLConnection

Tags: java, io, urlconnection

I need to add contents on file existing in tomcat server. So, I am using URLConnection to do this task.

Code I am trying:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/css/extractedcss.css");
    URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
    urlcon.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            urlcon.getOutputStream());
    out.write("New Text");
    out.close();
```

No any exception I am getting during execution of above code but when I look into the file, no any new text I am getting.

Please help!

Regards,

Comment: How do you "look into the file"? What code do you have accepting the POST on the server-side?

Answer (score 1):

You can't write directly to a file in your tomcat server - at least, not in HTTP you can't.

You'll have to write a servlet to do the writing for you, and then use a POST/PUT request to this servlet with the data you want written.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems to be fix my issue. I will try to implement this.